# Posting to Facebook Graph Api is slow

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, graph

I am creating a new Facebook app and there are actions attached to it, like the 'Listening to xxx' on Spotify.

Trouble is that the call takes around 6-7 seconds which is quite a long time. Beneath my code is the results of curl_getinfo. Is it supposed to be this slow?

```
    $attachment = array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'album' => 'sergeant peppers',
    );

    $opts = array(
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'facebook-php-3.1',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $attachment,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/APPNAME:listening'
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

The results of curl_getinfo:

```
[url] => https://graph.facebook.com/me/APPNAME:listening
[content_type] => text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
[http_code] => 400
[header_size] => 557
[request_size] => 238
[filetime] => -1
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 6.002449
[namelookup_time] => 0.024892
[connect_time] => 0.179322
[pretransfer_time] => 0.77444
[size_upload] => 362
[size_download] => 212
[speed_download] => 35
[speed_upload] => 60
[download_content_length] => 212
[upload_content_length] => 362
[starttransfer_time] => 1.775707
[redirect_time] => 0
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[redirect_url] =>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you have gotten a http 400 return (bad request), which indicates something went wrong. Maybe if you get your request right the request will be faster?

This post: [php cURL error in facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227860/php-curl-error-in-facebook-api)
indicates that you should remove 'CURLOPT_POST => true'
I also suggest adding 'CURLOPT_VERIFYPEER => false' if you still have problems.

Comment: +1. Good catch! I completely missed that in the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks, turned out I needed to be using the Extended OAuth Dialog box and that offline_access had been depreciated. Completely skimmed over the 400 myself.

Comment: How is your response time after the fix?

Answer (score 0):

**No, it is not.** [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6409442/517815) discusses the expected timings of the Facebook Graph API in more detail, though its problem diagnosis isn't applicable to your issue here.

Your best bet on discovering your bottleneck is network diagnostics, such as [`traceroute`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute), [`dig`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dig_%28Command%29), and the profiling features of cURL (as you're showing here). If you have a peer in a different locality, you can also try profiling from that location to see what changes.

Best of luck to you. This is extremely topical information, but it should be enough to get you started.